# No validator could be found for type: java.lang.Long :No validator could be found for type: java.lang.Long

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, annotations, ejb, pojo

I have an object class like which has no required field except Id. here is the code:

```
Entity
@XmlRootElement
@Table(name = "T_HOST_SPEC")
@Cacheable(false)
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = HostSpec.FIND_ALL, query = "SELECT m FROM HostSpec m")
    ,@NamedQuery(name = HostSpec.FIND_BY_IP_CONTEXT_PATH_PORT, query = "SELECT m FROM HostSpec m WHERE m.ip = :ip AND m.contextPath =:contextPath AND m.port =:port ")})
public class HostSpec extends AbstractEntity {



    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "HOST_SPEC_SEQUENCE_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "HOST_SPEC_SEQ", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "HOST_SPEC_SEQUENCE_GENERATOR")
    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Size(max =200 )
    @Column(name = "APP_NAME",length = 25)
    @XmlElement(name = "APP_NAME")
    private String appName;

    @Size(max =1000 )
    @Column(name = "APP_SERVER_INFO",length = 25)
    @XmlElement(name = "APP_SERVER_INFO")
    private String serverInfo;

    @Size(max =100 )
    @Column(name = "CONTEXT_PATH",length = 25)
    @XmlElement(name = "CONTEXT_PATH")
    private String contextPath;

    @Size(max =255 )
    @Column(name = "BUILD_DATE",length = 25)
    @XmlElement(name = "BUILD_DATE")
    private String buildDate;

    @Size(max =4000 )
    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION",length = 25)
    @XmlElement(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;


    @Size(max =50 )
    @Column(name = "IP",length = 25)
    @XmlElement(name = "IP")
    private String ip;

    @Size(max =200 )
    @Column(name = "MODULE_NAME",length = 25)
    @XmlElement(name = "MODULE_NAME")
    private String moduleName;

    @Size(max =100 )
    @Column(name = "NAME",length = 25)
    @XmlElement(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Size(max = 10)
    @XmlElement(name = "PORT")
    @Column(name = "PORT")
    private Long port;

    @Size(max =20 )
    @Column(name = "PROTOCOL",length = 25)
    @XmlElement(name = "PROTOCOL")
    private String protocol;


    @Size(max = 10)
    @XmlElement(name = "VERSION_CODE")
    @Column(name = "VERSION_CODE")
    private Long versionCode;

    @Size(max =100 )
    @Column(name = "VERSION_NAME",length = 25)
    @XmlElement(name = "VERSION_NAME")
    private String versionName;

    @Size(max =100 )
    @Column(name = "VIRTUAL_SERVER_NAME",length = 25)
    @XmlElement(name = "VIRTUAL_SERVER_NAME")
    private String serverName;

//getters & setters
```

when I try to run it, this exception is throws:
javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.lang.Long
please help

Comment: Can you try to remove `@Size(max = 10)` from attributes `port` and `versionCode`?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle -- thank you so much. this solved my problem

Comment: Ok, I write the answer for future googlers then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Size` is not intended to be used on type `Long` (you shall use `@Max` in this case).

Hence, you should replace `@Size(max = 10)` with the corresponding `@Max` annotation on fields `port` and `versionCode`

According to the javadoc, `@Size` can be used on following types :

- String (string length is evaludated)
- Collection (collection size is evaluated)
- Map (map size is evaluated)
- Array (array length is evaluated)
- null elements are considered valid.